# Should we change our description of the target audience?

Tags: discussion, scope

Added (quid): I am reactivating this in the hope of getting a clearer view of the communities opinion. I suggest we discuss this in general, keeping the self-learner aspect in mind but not as unique direction for the discussion, followin OP's wish.

---

Apart from our site name, the first thing a new visitor is most likely going to read is the “subtitle”:

> Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those involved in the field of teaching mathematics. It's 100% free, no registration required.

As already noted during [the poll on the site name](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13356/81465), one of the drawbacks of the site name *Mathematics Educators* is that, while having the advantage that it does not attract questions about math itself, it is everything but inviting for self-learners who want to ask on-topic questions. As a result it was suggested that at least the subtitle be welcoming for self-learners, should we decide that we welcome them. As [this seems to be the case](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114/75), I think that it is time to rediscuss the subtitle. (Note that this issue was [already discussed on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13182/81465), however, on basis of another site name.)

I am therefore asking for **suggestions and other considerations for our subtitle**, including other issues than self-learners. I think it is best to hold a seperate vote, should the need for it emerge (i.e., if there is no clear consensus here).

Keep in mind that we need to be careful to avoid attracting questions about math itself and hence titles like the following are arguably not a good idea:

> Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for math educators, enthusiasts, students, professors.

Comment: The poroposed on-topic section of the help center adresses this see http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/144/another-essential-meta-question-what-should-our-help-center-say-under-what-t/147#147 at the end. To me it seems this is sufficient, but I might be convincable it is not.

Comment: @quid: I would guess that some potential askers of good questions will not even get that far, if we leave the subtitle as it is. After all, the help center is not the very first thing somebody is going to see.

Comment: Yes, I would change the description from *involved in the field of teaching mathematics* to *interested in Mathematics Education*.

Comment: I like @BenjaminDickman's proposal of "interested in Mathematics Education".  In addition to welcoming self-learners, I think this might be more welcoming to Mathematics Education researchers, who we desperately want on this site, but who might not be involved in teaching mathematics themselves.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: The only problem I see is that students wanting to ask a question about math itself could feel invited as they are interested in *receiving* mathematics education (by us answering their questions). But maybe I am thinking too far. Anyway, why do you not extend your suggestion to an answer?

Comment: Could you indicate what kinds of questions from self-learners of mathematics, who are not educators or teachers, would be on-topic here? It would seem to me that questions from such a population would tend to be mathematical in nature, rather than about mathematics education, and therefore more off-topic than on.

Comment: @JDH To me it seems the thread linked to in OP discusses this in some detail. Do you ask for information in addition to this or had you just not noticed?

Comment: I've seen those examples now, thanks. I'm not really convinced. Frankly, I'm more worried about encouraging a population of participants who know little about teaching.

Answer (score 6):

Re-posting comment as an answer:

> Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange (MESE) is a question and answer site for those interested in Mathematics Education. It's 100% free; no registration required.

Comment: As I mention above, I like this suggestion.  However, it's possible that "interested in" would be better than "involved in".

Comment: @JimBelk Whoops! I seem to have misquoted myself. I also prefer that phrasing; changing it now.

Comment: The sentence will be necessarily rather short, but it could be somewhat longer than it is now, and we might want to take advantage of this. In a similar vein, it is in my opinion not a good idea to make it still "shorter" by using a somewhat repetitive formulation with "Mathematics Educators" and only "Mathematics Education." I am not against having Mathematics Education there, but to only say this hardly adds anything to the title in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

> Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those interested in the practice of teaching mathematics and research in mathematics education.

One might find a smoother formulation but to convey the general idea.

Comment: Picking up Jim Belk’s suggestion from [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/13191/81465), I suggest to replace *practice* by *process* and *teaching* by *learing and teaching.*

Comment: I am indifferent regarding practice or process (I took the practice from the wikipedia page on math ed); the suggestion of Jim Belk was teaching and learning not learning and teaching, and I think at least teaching should come first. And I am generally skeptical regarding learning at such places for reasons of clarity.